# Scroll to position with scrollview

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a scrollview which has a flatlist nested inside of it, so now I want to scroll to a certain position of the scrollview on button press, how can I achieve this?
Here is my code:

```
  <ScrollView
    ref={verticalRef}
  >
    {
      data.map( item => (
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
          <View >
            <FlatList
              data={item.data}
              numColumns={2}
              renderItem={thitem}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      ))
    }
  </ScrollView>
```

Here is the handler for the scroll:
const scrollToActiveIndex = (index) => {
setActiveIndex(index)
verticalRef.current?.scrollTo({
x: width * index,
animated: true
})
}

I have also attached a screenshot of my app. Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jva4w.png)

Comment: Please share some more code. This ain't enough.

Comment: first of all, you either use a scroll view and map, or just use a flatlist. no need for both. the flat list scrolls by itself.